# Difficulty specifying Java version to use in the command prompt

Tags: java, c#, runtime-error, command-prompt

While writing a test .DLL to wrap C# code into Java using JNI, after compiling my .DLL succesfully upon attempting to run my Java project I received the following error:

```
D:\>java Test1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: D://HeyLand.dll (D://HeyLand.dll is not a valid Win32 application. )
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1018)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:457)
        at Test1.<clinit>(Test1.java:5)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
Could not find the main class: Test1.  Program will exit.
```

I presume that this is because my Visual Studio project which built the  DLL uses a 32-bit compiler whereas my Java  version has a 64-bit compiler.

After some research I figured I need to use the function `java -version:"1.8.0_25` in the command prompt to force it to use the version I need, but although I have the location for both version of Java under my PATH environment variable I keep receiving this error:

```
D:\>java -version:"1.8.0_25" -version
Unable to locate JRE meeting specification "1.8.0_25"
```

I feel like it is a simple input error on my part, but I can't seem to figure out what it is.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

---

**Question update:**

I attempted to further specify the location and receive the same error, although it is most definitely there.

```
D:\>java -version:"D:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe" -version
Unable to locate JRE meeting specification "D:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe"
```

Comment: How about specifying the absolute path to the right java.exe?

Comment: I attempted to specify the path as you said, and am receiving the same error for some reason.

Comment: No, I mean running the specific version of java.exe: `d:\> "D:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe" Test`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to run the Java version required is to simply specify which version of java to run, and not use the version-forcing function in the command prompt, like so:

```
D:\>"D:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe" -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
```